# How can I pin/unpin a specific kernel version/package in fedora 21?

Tags: fedora, yum

I'm currently running fedora 21 with a btrfs filesystem. Unfortunately, I'm currently forced to stick to the oldest of my three kernel versions (3.18.7-200.fc21.x86_64) on boot since newer versions seem to have broken btrfs support.

I do believe fedora clears up older kernel versions (and retains the latest three) so, this might be a problem if I have *no* bootable kernel versions

Here's what I'd like to do

1. I'd like to retain the known good kernel indefinitely (so fedora dosen't prune an 'old' kernel version)
2. I'd like to be able to upgrade and replace the two newer kernels so I can test and switch as soon as there's an upgrade.

How would I do this?

Comment: Can you select the kernel using Grub?  I use Ubuntu rather than than Fedora, and have Grub always present a menu of installed kernel versions to select from.  A default version boots in X seconds if I do nothing.  A while back I had a similar issue, and had to revert to using an older kernel version.

Comment: Yes I can - and I'm picking the oldest kernel I have of three. I don't want to be in a situation where I don't have ANY usable kernels. I want to *ensure* the known good kernel version dosen't get accidentally wiped, since fedora seems to keep only the last 3 *and* the latest 2 don't work. Clarified the question somewhat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit /etc/yum.conf to include the line exclude=kernel-3.18.7

And/ or

In */etc/default/grub*  make grub_default={place of desired kernel}  assumin  no debug/rescue kernels this rould be *grub_default=2*